# fluid-fixed design

Tags: css

I need to have two inline divs, the left div should be fluid and the right should be fixed. The minimum width for the left fluid column should be 801px and the maximum width for the left div should be 1250px. The right fixed div width should always be an exact 250px.

Can someone please show me how to do this? If the body width is 1500px for example, the left fluid div should grow and push the right div out to 1250px and stop. If the body content is 801px then the left div should be around 550px.

I've already asked this question but wasn't able to get anything that worked.

```
.intro {
  float:left;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  padding:10px 0;
}

.intro-right,
.intro-left{
  display:inline;
}

.intro-right {
  float:left;
  width:250px;
  margin-right:20px;
  height:200px;
}

.intro-left {
  min-width:801px;
  max-width:1250px;
  height:200px;
}

<div class="intro">
  <div class="intro-left">
    <h2><a href="#">Test</a></h2>
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>

  <div class="intro-right">right fixed</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you won't be able to do it with pure css

Comment: OK, thanks. Can you tell me what I should use? Tables?

Comment: i don't know... me hardly use table, give it a go. otherwise javascript, you hide right-intro, set left to 100%, on load calculate the size for left make appear right from the right while decreasing left + a fallback if no javascript with fixed width for both

Comment: @mikakun, thanks. I will look into this solution and let you know how it works for me.

Comment: @mikakun, thanks, a Javascript solution was what worked for me, thank you. If you'd like to post this answer, I'll credit you for it.

Comment: ok then, but i'm just copy/pasting !

Answer (score 0):

try with javascript in a way that will look not too bad on page load

for example you hide right-intro, with left set to 100%,

on load calculate the size for left make appear right from the right while decreasing left + a fallback if no javascript with fixed width for both

NB: add a window resize event listener